# How to see ec2 instance details that are created by data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline

I have created an ec2 instance using data pipeline. TerminateAfter field value was set to 2 hours. How can i verify the created ec2 instance details(like ip, java versions...) using aws ec2 console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see the instance attributes like ip, region etc., in the dashboard. But if you want system specific information like java version, you have to ssh into the created instance. Make sure you are looking for the instance in the correct region.